# ToString call on dynamic type variable behaves differently in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can someone explain to me the difference between these two string variables :

```
        dynamic dateStrAsDynamic = "12/10/2013";
        var dateStrFromDynamic = dateStrAsDynamic.ToString();
        var regularDateStr = "12/10/2013";
```

These two behave exactly the same way but while debugging calling `DateTime.Parse` on the first one tells me that this dynamic operation is not supported while debugging, I mean "which dynamic operation?", whatever dynamic operation it is; must it not have been over?

The IL code generated by calling `DateTime.Parse` on those two (of course after `ToString` is called and assigned to dateStrFromDynamic) have a large difference as well that I am not able to grasp totally.

Do these two really have a difference, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I mean "which dynamic operation?"

The one that invokes a method using a dynamic variable as the argument.

Note that the type `dateStrFromDynamic` will still be `dynamic` - the compiler doesn't know that `ToString()` will definitely return a `string`. The result of almost any dynamic operation is another dynamic value - if you want to tell the compiler that you want the type of `dateStrFromDynamic` to be `string`, you need to make that explicit:

```
string dateStrFromDynamic = dateStrAsDynamic.ToString();
```

Or just:

```
string dateStrFromDynamic = dateStrAsDynamic;
```

(given that it really *is* a string to start with).

So yes, there *is* an enormous difference between `dateStrFromDynamic` and `regularDateStr` - and if you hover over `var` in Visual Studio, it will become more obvious as it will tell you the type that the compiler has inferred for each variable.

Comment: Is the latter example equivalent to `string dateStrFromDynamic = (string)dateStrAsDynamic;`? Or maybe more clearly stated, does the compiler generate a cast like that?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Yes, the compiler will insert a cast automatically. I *believe* it can use implicit user-defined conversions in that case, too - but it won't use *explicit* user-defined conversions unless you've been explicit about it in your code - so it's not *quite* equivalent to having the cast in the source code.